Delete a HuggingFace Sentence Transformers from RAM memory?
I'm using the following script to load a Sentence Transformers using LangChain :
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings

embedding_function = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
    model_name="sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L12-v2", model_kwargs={'device': 'cpu'})

After the usage, I want to delete the model and unload it from the RAM memory.
python==3.11.7
langchain==0.1.16
langchain_community==0.0.32
langchain_core==0.1.42
sentence-transformers==2.6.1

I tried following the usual python deleting process like thisn it does not work :
import gc
del embedding_function
gc.collect()

I'm inspecting the memory of the terminal in the Windows Task Manager. When I remove the line embedding_function = ..., the memory is below 50MB; when I add it, the memory is still above 400 MB.

What is your actual question? How do you conclude that your approach is not working? Is there code which you are not showing us which adds new references to the model?

My question is how to remove the model from the memory ? Not any other single line of code is used. You can reproduce the behaviour by running those lines.

Going forward, please [edit] your question to clarify it. I copied your comment to the question so you can simply delete it now.

For clearing from GPU memory and monitoring what's happening, you can use these functions:
import gc,torch

def print_vram_info():
    free_memory, total_memory = torch.cuda.mem_get_info()

    free_memory_gb = free_memory / 1024**3
    total_memory_gb = total_memory / 1024**3

    print(f"Free Memory: {free_memory_gb:.2f}/{total_memory_gb:.2f} GB")

def clear_vram(variable=None):
    if variable != None:
        del variable
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    gc.collect()

